# Delete rows in table based on values in other table

Tags: mysql

I have a simplified table like this (table1):

```
id | note
----------------------------------
 1 | some note
 2 | some note
 3 | another note
 4 | some note
```

and another one (table2):

```
id | note
----------------------------------
 1 | some note
 2 | another note
 3 | some note
 4 | another note
```

Based on id from table1 I want to delete rows from table2 where table1.note is equal table2.note.

If I provide tabel1´s id=3, rows with id 2 and 4 of table2 should be deleted.

I tried:

```
DELETE FROM table2
JOIN table1 WHERE id = ?
WHERE table1.note = table2.note
```

But I am getting "ER_PARSE_ERROR".

What is the correct mysql syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do `join` between table1 and table2 in the `delete` statement.

```
DELETE T2 FROM Table2 T2
JOIN Table1 T1
ON T1.note = T2.note
AND T1.id =3
```

Comment: Thx, this works, could you explain what the "T2" mean in the first line? Can they be omitted? When searching online I only find examples with simple "DELETE FROM table" statements. Same goes for the T1.

Comment: @Hans, giving alias name so that you don't have to use full table name to refer to the column name, here note column is same in two tables, so you need to prefix table name or table alias name.

Comment: Could you show how to write it without the alias name? I dont get why the alias is double in the first line.

Comment: @Hans, you can replace T2 with Table2 and T1 with Table1 and don't alias if it is confusing

Comment: I tried 
DELETE FROM Table2
JOIN Table1
ON Table1.note = Table2.note
AND Table1.id =3

you mean like this? It didnt work.

Comment: DELETE Table2 FROM TAble2 JOin Table1 on TAble1.note = Table2.note and Table1.id =3

Comment: thx alot for the clarification :) I think I get it now, new to sql ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query as below you can specify `WHERE` clause only once instead you use `ON` clause to complete your join part or  you can use `AND` after `WHERE` for more conditions

```
DELETE t2.*
FROM
  table2 t2
  JOIN table1  t1
ON t1.note = t2.note 
WHERE t1.id = 3
```